# How to delete the files from a directory, when the names of the files are saved in the CSV file, using CMD?

Tags: cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I used the following command to delete files (the name of the files are saved in a CSV file) from my directory:

```
del >dir list.csv
```

But it deleted the file list.csv and created a *dir* file.
What command should I use?

Comment: `del /?` from a command prompt.

Comment: and [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: A CSV file is a plain text file with `C`omma `S`eparated `V`alues. If when you've finished your code, it fails to work as expected, then [add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63254645/edit), together with a representative example of your CSV content, and explain to us what encoding type it uses, `ASCII`, or `Unicode`, _(and if Unicode, which specifically, `UTF-8`, with or without `BOM`, `UTF-16 LE`, `UTF-16 BE`, `OEM`, `UTF-7`, `UTF-32`)_. It would also assist us if you were to let us know what type of file endings you've used in the file, `CRLF`, `LF`, `CR`.